# No QUARTER() in DAX? Really?

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

While building a Calendar table with PowerQuery for a PowerPivot model in Excel 2013 I use its [Date.QuarterOfYear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253453) function to get the number of the quarter.

Building the same thing in SSAS Tabular requires some workarounds. There's no equivalent DAX function to get number of the quarter from a DATE. Strangely, DAX has YEAR() and MONTH(), but no QUARTER().

Are nested `IF` or `SWITCH` statements really the only way in DAX to get the quarter number?

What is the reason for the absence such a simple and useful function? Am I overlooking the supreme wisdom of this decision?

Comment: There are other ways besides IFs or SWITCH: you can use (MONTH([Date])+2)/3

Comment: Thanks, Rory, for idea!

Comment: Hi @erop, have you chosen an answer?

Comment: @drmyrnz, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32586553/409317

Comment: @erop Ah, cool. Glad you came to a solution. :)

Comment: According to learn.microsoft.com DAX does have QUARTER function now. But I can`t make it. I upgraded SSAS, VisualStudio, SSDT, model level to 2019 and I still get errors "can not resolve the name quarter".Could you help me please?

Answer (score 15):

I found an answer in [this](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/microsoft-excel-2013-building-data-models-with-powerpivot-9780735676343) great book!

One should use `=ROUNDUP(MONTH([Date])/3, 0)` to get quarter number.

Answer (score 8):

> No QUARTER() in DAX?

Yes, that is correct.

> Really?

Yes, it's crazy and doesn't make any sense. Fortunately the workaround is just dividing the month by 3.

#### Solution:

```
VAR quarterNumber = CEILING(MONTH([Date])/3,1)
```

#### Alternate Solutions:

Since DAX has multiple ways to round numbers, these will also work:

```
VAR quarterNumber = ISO.CEILING(MONTH([Date])/3,1)
VAR quarterNumber = ROUNDUP(MONTH([Date])/3,0)
```

#### Which Solution is Best:

- For the values used in my examples, the results will be identical.
- For other examples there can be small and subtle differences in the result depending on standards or the type of CPU being used.
- ROUNDUP is probably more intuitive to Excel people.
- CEILING is probably more intuitive to math people.
- ISO.CEILING is ugly to look at in code, personal opinion.

Answer (score 5):

It's not documented but this works:

> INT(FORMAT([Date], "q"))

Comment: This looks like it might be slower, because it's also converting to a string then back to a number again.

Answer (score 5):

DAX now has quarters! This is some date data:
[image: Dates]

And these are how you get the quarters and quarter numbers:
[image: Date quarters]
[image: Date quarter numbers]

The results of these are below:

[image: Date quarter slicers]

Answer (score 0):

I think they are assuming you'd create a date dimension in which your Quarter is pre-defined, including the Financial Year. I live in Australia where the Financial Year ends in June, and I've always pre defined the quarters as an added column to the table. IF you're using Power BI/Power Query you can add a query in the M code level (at the import stage).

Answer (score 0):

Add column for get quarter :

```
Quarter = summary_bu_USD[Start Period].[Quarter]
```

Add column again and group year in column:

```
QuarterYear = YEAR(summary_bu_USD[Start Period])&" "&"Q"&RIGHT(summary_bu_USD[Quarter],1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jOT4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this command:

```
=FORMAT(Date[Date],"q")
```

And combined them to create things like this

```
="Q." & FORMAT(Date[Date],"q") & " - "&Date[Year] = e.g. Q.1 - 2021
```